Is there a standard for smaller margins?
As title states, I'm curious whether there is any standard one may adopt if they are looking to utilize margins narrower than those provided by one's standard LaTeX document. I understand that one can set one's own preferences via packages like geometry, but I was wondering whether that was all left up to one's own standards or whether there was any sort of secondary standard one may reasonably adopt if one is to utilize narrower margins? As an example: what sort of standard might the page margins in a book like Thomas Jech's "Set Theory" follow?

I guess 1" on all sides is a standard of sorts, although I wouldn't really recommend that. Chapter 2 of the Koma-Script manual and Chapter 8 of Elements of Typographic Style discuss how to choose appropriate margins, but neither give any specific recommendations.

This is more a typography than a (La)TeX question. The LaTeX question would be how to set those smaller margins and you are already answering it yourself in the question. Therefore it is more or less off-topic IMHO.

Books typically don't use a4 paper. It is not that latex margins are large it's that a4 is too wide for single column printing, so you can not have small margins without over long text lines
